# Why is Chrome.storage.sync storage reset when new page is loaded?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, storage

```
var userCharacters = [];

window.onkeyup = function(e){

userCharacters.push(e.key);

chrome.storage.sync.set({'userInput':userCharacters})

if(e.key == "Shift")
  chrome.storage.sync.get('userInput',function(userText){
    alert(userText.userInput);
  });

}
```

I'm trying to store and retrieve data labeled 'userInput', but every time I open up a new page or tab it resets the userText.userInput value. Can someone please explain why this is happening and how we can go around that?

Comment: Try with just `alert(userText);`

Comment: Unfortunately, that just returns [object Object].

Comment: Sorry, I'm not 100% of what you mean. Is there anyway you could provide a concrete example?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Every time you load a new page, the `userCharacters[]` array is defined as `[]` and then has characters added to it. When you run `chrome.storage.sync.set({'userInput':userCharacters})`, the existing data is overwritten.
To solve this, load the data already in storage into `userCharacters` before the user adds more.

```
var userCharacters;
chrome.storage.sync.get('userInput',function(userText){
  userCharacters = userText.userInput;
});
window.onkeyup = function(e){
  userCharacters.push(e.key);
  chrome.storage.sync.set({'userInput':userCharacters})
  if(e.key == "Shift")
    chrome.storage.sync.get('userInput',function(userText){
      alert(userText.userInput);
    });
}
```